# How to re-launch a child_process with new arguments?

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

Currently I’m working on an Electron.js project where I need to use shell commands to establish continuous communication with a remote server. To do so I’m spawning Node’s *child_process* and attaching a callback function to digest data being received alike so:

```
let process = child_process.spawn(“myCommand -–argument1”, [], PROCESS_OPTIONS);
 
process.stdout.on(“data” (data) => {
    callback(data);
});
```

Every now and then when a user provides an input through the application’s UI, I have to pass some additional arguments to the process that is already running. To accomplish that I’m killing the process and starting a new one with updated command: `myCommand --argument1 --argument2`

The problem with that approach is that it leaves 2-3 zombie processes running in the task manager under the main Electron process every time I re-launch the command.
[Task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsHzd.png)

I am new to Node.js, could anyone suggest a better solution to this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can communicate with the child process via the stdin/stdout.
So this should to execute code on each message).
Example:

```
//parent.js
const childProcess = require('child_process');

const child = childProcess.spawn('node', [`${__dirname}\\child.js`]);
child.stdout.on('data', data => {
   const msg = data.toString('utf8');
   console.log('Parent got message from child:', msg);
});

child.stderr.on('data', data => {
   console.log('child error:', data);
});

let itr = 0;
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
   child.stdin.write(`${itr++}`);
}, 1000);

setTimeout(() => {
   clearInterval(intervalId);
   child.kill(0);
   process.kill(0);
}, 7000);
```

---

```
// child.jd
process.stdin.on('data', data => {
   const msg = Number(data.toString('utf8'));
   const pow2 = Math.pow(msg, 2);
   process.stdout.write(`Hello from child process (got: ${msg} reply: ${pow2})`);
});
```

---

```
$> node parent.js
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 0 reply: 0)
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 1 reply: 1)
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 2 reply: 4)
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 3 reply: 9)
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 4 reply: 16)
Parent got message from child: Hello from child process (got: 5 reply: 25)
```